# Does it follow $BA = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem from paul halmos books

> If $A$ and $B $ are  linear transformation  on a vector space  , and if $AB = 0 $. does  it follow $BA = 0$ ?

My attempt : I think yes ,If i take $A(x,y) = ( 0,y) , B(x,y) = (x, 0)$ then $AB(x,y) =A(x, 0)=0$

then again $BA= BA(x,y) = B(0, y) = 0$

Is its true ?

Comment: You gave one example, which is not enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true.  For a counterexample, consider 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$

Comment: this example  didn't came in my minds.....!!

Comment: @jasmine for future reference, it's a good idea to try examples with mostly $1$'s and $0$'s.